# How to resolve Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. in android studio 3.6.2

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, build, android-emulator

I created my first project in Android Studio and set up emulator but when I run the application I get the error below and the build output: build failed. How can I fix this?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.2-6040484.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.2-6040484 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.2-6040484 available for offline mode.
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to the error I got (exactly the same as yours). It probably happened when I updated Android Studio... Here's what I did and it worked:

Open any project, and do "FILE" > "PROJECT STRUCTURE..." (or the shortcut Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S). Go to the project section (at the very top) of the window that just appeared and choose the latest version of Android Gradle Puglin (= Android Studio version) and Gradle (now it's 3.6.2 for Android Studio and 6.3 for Gradle). Once done: "APPLY" & "OK".

Second thing to do: "VIEW" > "TOOL WINDOWS" > "GRADLE". With the window that just opened, click on "TOGGLE OFFLINE MODE", the penultimate icon at the top of the window (it *must not* be highlighted anymore), and keep this window for a little while. Now build your project/create the apk file to run Gradle and download the necessary, since you have changed version (Connect your pc to the internet!).

Normally (at least for me), Android Studio will download what you need and you'll just have to wait a bit. As soon as the build is finished, go back to the Gradle window and reactivate "TOGGLE OFFLINE MODE" (it *must* be highlighted). Rebuild your project to make sure it works (I don't know if this step is necessary, but better too much than too little!), and you're done! No more errors and no more need to connect to the Internet!

Answer (score 0):

These resources need to be installed and it can't be synced offline so you need to connect to internet and then sync build.gradle again in order to download these resources.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, much appreciated. I have already sync and it shows successful but the error still persists please what else can I do

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Hardik. While this didn't fix the original poster's, your answer could be helpful for others. To improve the quality, I suggest you add details about how to install and synchronize the build files.

Comment: The problem can exist in your current gradle so try installing new gradle from gradle.org and set it's path in Android Studio, this should work in your case.

Comment: I don't really understand what you meant by installing grade. But I downloaded the offline components and set it up as required but the problem still persist, please I need further assistance, thanks

Comment: Gradle files are those files which are required to build your project on Android Studio and building apk. For any reason if they are not merged properly, you can delete the existing gradle and install new gradle files from its official website gradle.org and then you can set it's path from Android Studio to build your project.

Answer (score 0):

The error message happened to me after I changed file names and file types.

I tried:

> Build> Clear Build, and
> Build > Rebuild

Both didn't work.

Although "Sync Project with Gradle Files" removed the error.

Note: I'm using ANdroid Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1

Also, it worked when I realised I have removed `tools:.MainActivity` on my `constraint` xml.

Answer (score 0):

If you added any custom attribute to the attrs.xml, just make sure the name of the attribute is not duplicated with the default attribute names and put the unique attribute name.